# Unable to create an emulator using android studio

Tags: android, testing, mobile, android-emulator, manual-testing

I installed android studio on MacBook Pro but when I try to create a virtual device it shows me an error saying that cpu does not support vt-x.

Comment: Check if vtx is supported in your mac. Run this command **sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu.features** and check if VMX feature is available in featured list. https://build5nines.com/check-hyper-v-intel-vt-x-virtualization-support-on-macos-computer/

Comment: I tried this one but it does not show any features. I update the software also, still I am facing the same issue. Please suggest me a solution what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to download the SDKs you are interested in from Android Studio Tools menu -> Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager or enter image description here from the menu bar.

Don't forget to install the intel x86 emulator accelerator haxm from the SDK Manager - this will speed up significantly your android virtual device.

Then proceed as you mentioned in your question.

You can find more information here.

EDIT : From the comments your OS X version is 10.7.5 and Android Studio runs on 10.8.5 so you either :

Update your OS X installation
Install Eclipse and use the ADT plugin from google on your current configuration.

Comment: Seems like you forgot to attach the link to: "You can find more information here."